# Ruby nested each do + array concatenation

Tags: ruby, arrays

*newbie apologies..

The following code:

```
dates = ['Transaction_Date','Renewal_Date']
dateoptions = ['Year','Month','Date']
word1 = "Amount"

dates.each do |x|
  puts word1 + " by " + x
  end
```

Returns

```
Amount by Transaction_Date
Amount by Renewal_Date
```

I would like the outcome to be a concatenation of the dates and dateoptions, like so

```
Amount by Transaction_Date (Year)
Amount by Transaction_Date (Month)
Amount by Transaction_Date (Date)
Amount by Renewal_Date (Year)
Amount by Renewal_Date (Month)
Amount by Renewal_Date (Month)
```

I was thinking of doing a nested "each do" but I still wouldn't know how to address the concatenation of the two arrays.

Appreciate your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use nested `each`:

```
dates = ['Transaction_Date','Renewal_Date']
dateoptions = ['Year','Month','Date']
word1 = "Amount"

dates.each do |d|
  dateoptions.each do |option|
    puts "#{word1} by #{d} (#{option})"
  end
end
```

Or you can use [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-product)

```
dates.product(dateoptions) do |d, option|
  puts "#{word1} by #{d} (#{option})"
end
```

Comment: Perfect, both options help me a lot. Thank you @falsetru

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-product) method:

```
dates.product(dateoptions).each do |date, option|
  puts "#{word1} by #{date} (#{option})"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dates = ['Transaction_Date','Renewal_Date']
dateoptions = ['Year','Month','Date']
word1 = "Amount"

dates.each do |x|
  dateoptions.each do |y|
    puts "#{word1} by #{x} (#{y})"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
2.1.2 :009 > dates.each do |e|
2.1.2 :010 >     dateoptions.each do |o|
2.1.2 :011 >       puts "#{word1} by #{e} (#{o})"
2.1.2 :012?>     end
2.1.2 :013?>   end
Amount by Transaction_Date (Year)
Amount by Transaction_Date (Month)
Amount by Transaction_Date (Date)
Amount by Renewal_Date (Year)
Amount by Renewal_Date (Month)
Amount by Renewal_Date (Date)
```