# Nested arrays and generating truth-table-like combinations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a nested array like this:

```
levels = [["d11", "d12"],["d21", "d22"],["d31", "d32"],["d41", "d42"]]
```

I need to generate something like a truth table. I need a set of arrays populated by the combinations of different sub arrays like this:

```
levels =  [["d11", "d21", "d31", "d41"],
           ["d11", "d21", "d31", "d42"],
           ["d11", "d21", "d32", "d41"],
           ["d11", "d21", "d32", "d42"],
           ["d11", "d22", "d31", "d41"],
           ["d11", "d22", "d31", "d42"]]
```

and so on, until the last one. In total, there would be 16 combinations.

I nested each methods to iterate over the sub arrays, but am not getting the expected output.

```
<% levels.each do |p| %>
 <% p.each do |c| %>
  <p> <%= c %></p>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682287/ruby-nested-each-do-array-concatenation), which is kind of what I want, but I don't have separated arrays, I have them all inside a big array, and I do not know how to replicate his iteration over the two separate arrays in my multidimensional array.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
levels.first.product(*levels.drop(1))
```

or

```
first, *rest = levels
first.product(*rest)
```

Output:

```
[
  ["d11", "d21", "d31", "d41"],
  ["d11", "d21", "d31", "d42"],
  ["d11", "d21", "d32", "d41"],
  ["d11", "d21", "d32", "d42"],
  ["d11", "d22", "d31", "d41"],
  ["d11", "d22", "d31", "d42"],
  ["d11", "d22", "d32", "d41"],
  ["d11", "d22", "d32", "d42"],
  ["d12", "d21", "d31", "d41"],
  ["d12", "d21", "d31", "d42"],
  ["d12", "d21", "d32", "d41"],
  ["d12", "d21", "d32", "d42"],
  ["d12", "d22", "d31", "d41"],
  ["d12", "d22", "d31", "d42"],
  ["d12", "d22", "d32", "d41"],
  ["d12", "d22", "d32", "d42"]
]
```

Comment: Or, if `levels` can be mutated, `levels.shift.product(*levels)`.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, thanks a lot guys! .. by mutated you mean a variation in the amount of items of each sub array?

Comment: @DiegoNiño "mutation" means that it will change the value stored in your original variable `levels`. The other versions leave `levels` how it was, and the result those methods return must be saved in their own variables. When in doubt, IMO, avoid mutation as it can be hard to reason about and be slightly more error prone.

Comment: @user12341234 oh! i get it now, well yes, in this case i avoided the mutation because i need the original array untouched, thanks for the quick clarification

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) and it can be calculated like this:

```
>> levels.inject(&:product).map(&:flatten)
=> [["d11", "d21", "d31", "d41"], ["d11", "d21", "d31", "d42"], ["d11", "d21", "d32", "d41"], ["d11", "d21", "d32", "d42"], ["d11", "d22", "d31", "d41"], ["d11", "d22", "d31", "d42"], ["d11", "d22", "d32", "d41"], ["d11", "d22", "d32", "d42"], ["d12", "d21", "d31", "d41"], ["d12", "d21", "d31", "d42"], ["d12", "d21", "d32", "d41"], ["d12", "d21", "d32", "d42"], ["d12", "d22", "d31", "d41"], ["d12", "d22", "d31", "d42"], ["d12", "d22", "d32", "d41"], ["d12", "d22", "d32", "d42"]]
```

Though I would bet that calculations like this probably should be done in a controller or model, rather than in a view.

Comment: Yes indeed!, i took your advice and placed my code in the controller. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

[Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-product) certainly should be used here, but (for illustration) one could instead use recursion.

```
def cartesian(arr)
  return arr.first.map { |e| [e] } if arr.size == 1
  first, *rest = arr
  first.each_with_object([]) { |e,arr| cartesian(rest).each { |a| arr << [e, *a] } }
end

cartesian(levels)
  #=> [["d11", "d21", "d31", "d41"],
  #    ["d11", "d21", "d31", "d42"],
  #   ...
  #    ["d12", "d22", "d32", "d42"]] 

cartesian(levels).size
  #=> 16
```

Comment: This is a very good illustration of what i needed, am definitely going to take my time to experiment with this and learn the principles you applied, thanks!